# using IndexOf on string to pick out certain words

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pick out certain words that a user has inputted.
Basically, what is below is a form that people on my website have to fill out in the exact same format.
The only difference is, however, is everything inside the "[" and "]" is the only thing they can change

however, it does not matter if they add spaces before the text starts, and after the text starts (meaning before "Trade Partner" and after "By sending this message..." sentence)

```
Trade Partner: [OMeGaXX] 
My Items: ["https://www.roblox.com/The-Classic-ROBLOX-Fedora-item?id=1029025"] 
Their Items: ["https://www.roblox.com/The-Classic-ROBLOX-Fedora-item?id=1029025"]

By sending this message I agree that I have not been bribed or blackmailed to send this and I am completely willing to take part in this trade.
```

I need help trying to pick out everything in the block quotes. For example, the name "OMeGaXX" in the brackets for Trade Partner.
Also there can be multiple items in "My Items", which are separated by commas: it is the exact same as "Their Items". I'm wondering how I would add all the urls in "My Items" and "Their Items" into a URL.

In addition, the last sentence must always be in
Thanks!

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have tried this, the variable body being the text in the question. 'var data = body.match(/\[.+?\]/gi);'  It puts everything inside [] into an array,HOWEVER, how would i separate them into "My Items", "Their Items" and "Trade partner"?

Comment: Update your question with what you your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find what's between the brackets you can use *regular expressions*. Say the message is saved inside the variable `msg`, then we can create an array of the matches with

```
var data = msg.match(/\[.+?\]/gi);
```

This basically searches the string for any pattern that matches `[anytexthere]`, and puts them all in an array for you.

The elements are still within brackets, though, so remove the first and last character of the string with the following code:

```
data[1].substring(1,data[1].length-1);
```

To check if the last sentence is in, you can check if the last 143 characters (in this case) of the string are equal to that sentence. To do so, use

```
var lastSentence = msg.substring(-143,0);
if(lastSentence === "By sending this message I agree that I have not been bribed or blackmailed to send this and I am completely willing to take part in this trade.") {
    //Yay, the last sentence is there!
}
```

Comment: Regexes are greedy. This will match everything from the first bracket to the last in the whole string.

Comment: How do I know which is which though? I want to be able to separate "Trade Partner" from "My Items" and "Their Items", whilst at the same time checking that the last sentence is there.

Comment: I was afraid so too, but in this case it will not match everything from the first to last bracket.

Comment: The elements of the array are in the same order as the message. So, the first element (`data[0]`) is the "Trade Partner", the second "My Items", and the third "Their Items".

Comment: Help? How would I separate them ?!

Comment: @Pandaqi BUT Remember "My Items" and "Their Items" can have more than 1

Comment: Oh yes, but @tanenbring's answer dealt with that. Simply use `split(", ")` on the element to split URLs at commas.

Comment: Thanks, But how would I check that last sentence is there?

Comment: Also it returns things still inside the [ and ]. How would I just have the text on its own?

Comment: I edited my answer to include answers to your questions.

Comment: @Pandaqi Why isn't that greedy?

Comment: The question mark basically means "try to match stuff as little as possible". If i hadn't included it, or I had used `(.+)?`, it would have matched everything from first to last bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Probably don't want to use indexOf; use a regex instead:

```
var str = `
 Trade Partner: [OMeGaXX] My Items: ["https://www.roblox.com/The-Classic-ROBLOX-Fedora-item?id=1029025"] Their Items: ["https://www.roblox.com/The-Classic-ROBLOX-Fedora-item?id=1029025"]
    `,
    regex = /\[([^\]]*)\]/g,
    tradePartner = str.match(regex)[1],
    myItems = str.match(regex)[1].split(","),
    theirItems = str.match(regex)[1].split(",");
```

Everything in the match at index 1 will be the group in the regex (everything between the parentheses).

In your code you should check things aren't null:
`(match = str.match(regex)) ? match[1] : null;`

Comment: Why do you use three backticks and not one?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into regex.

```js
var msg = 'Trade Partner: [OMeGaXX] \nMy Items: ["https://www.roblox.com/The-Classic-ROBLOX-Fedora-item?id=1029025"] \nTheir Items: ["https://www.roblox.com/The-Classic-ROBLOX-Fedora-item?id=1029025"]\n\nBy sending this message I agree that I have not been bribed or blackmailed to send this and I am completely willing to take part in this trade."';

var matched = msg.match(/\[.*\]/g);
$(function(){
  $("span").html(matched.join("<br>"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Matched: <span></span>
```

Regex explanation:

```
/
    \[        match the exact character [
        .*    match everything
    \]        match the exact character ]
/g            match multiple occurrences in the string
```